# Curl error while trying to connect

Tags: bash, curl, testflight

I always used the curl command, now i have some problems with it.

I do `curl --verbose https://testflightapp.com`  and its failed. the result is:
`About to connect() to testflightapp.com port 80 (#0)  Trying 110.173.143.147...Operation timed out`

If I try manually on the browser its OK.

any solutions?

Comment: Are the curl command and the browser running on the same computer?

Comment: Yes On the same computer. i see that telnet also doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems curl is going to the wrong port: You're requesting a https URL, which, by default, is on port 443, and curl is going to 80.

Check if you have a curl version that supports HTTPS (has openssl/tls bindings).

Cheers,
Ricardo

Comment: I wrote it with https, but on my script it http. When i use https it really trying to connect to port 443,but don't connect.